# Given a sorted array of n elements, sort a subset n/2 elements in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I have a sorted array of n elements. Now I am given n/2 elements each of which belong to the sorted array. The n/2 elements are taken at random from the sorted array. How to sort these n/2 elements in linear time?

Comment: Do you know anything in particular about those elements (e.g. are they integers, for example?) Are duplicates allowed?

Comment: Only non-comparison sorts can run better than `O(n lg n)` - See [Radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) and [Counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) sorts for ideas of how the "sorted indices" (which function as ordering weights) might be useful.

Comment: @templatetypedef. Your answer below is what I was looking for. Thanks. Duplicates or no duplicates doesn't matter as you already explained in your answer.

Comment: @user3299864 if so, please mark templatetypedef answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach involves hashing. Build a hash set that contains all n / 2 elements drawn from the array. If duplicates are allowed, instead build a hash table from elements to their frequencies. This will take O(n) time, on expectation.

Then, iterate across the sorted array in ascending order and, for each element of the array, check if it's in the hash set / hash table. If so, append that element to the output array (and, if duplicates are allowed, do so once per copy of the element in the set). This will take O(1) time, on expectation, per element of the array, and therefore this step takes time O(n) as well.

Therefore, the total runtime is O(n), on expectation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the elements fit into one array, you can use another boolean array, which mark what elements have been selected `boolean [] selected`

So by walking through this array, and only print out the element that has been marked as selected, you can have the desired effect.

Edit: by decorating the return object, we can even sort a subset of those random values

```
boolean [] selected;
Object [] data;// the array of elements

ReturnObject getRandom(){
    int index = random();
    selected[index] = true;
    return new ReturnObject(index,data[index]);
}

void printSelected(){

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(selected[i]){
           print(data[i]);
        }
    }
}

void printSubset(ReturnObject[]set){
    boolean []selected = ....
    for(int i = 0; i < set.length; i++){
        selected[set[i].index] = true;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(selected[i]){
            print(data[i]);
        }
    }
}


class ReturnObject{//Class decorating the return object, which includes its index in the data array
    int index;
    Object data;
}
```

Comment: How would you fill in the `selected` array in O(n) time if the numbers were given to you by an external source, rather than generated in the way that you've shown here?

Comment: @templatetypedef Actually you can decorate the return object by also including its index in the array

Comment: That's true. I was under the impression that the problem was "A subset of size n / 2 is given to you and it's created out of your control. After receiving the set, go sort it." That would prevent approaches like what you've described here.

Comment: @templatetypedef edit code to illustrate my point, this approach can allow us to have two different functions, one is print all random values, one is print a subset of those random, and also get rid of the hashmap, but add another class (which is good and bad) :)